# Is there a Spring-supported way to get a Properties object from the application environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, environment

So I need to get a `Properties` object to instantiate a message consumer. In my Spring Boot application, I use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in a `@Configuration` class to load the right properties into the app. Depending on the deploy environment, I can have multiple active profiles and property files.

I've tried to find the most painless and Spring-supported way to do this, but the following methods are what I could come up with:

1. Use `PropertiesLoaderUtils` to explicitly load properties from specific files. I do something like `"application-"+ activeProfile + ".properties"`. This is my best method so far, but I want to avoid having to specify the properties file name and re-loading properties if possible.
2. Use the `Environment` class and a loop to cycle through all the loaded properties and load them into a `Properties` object. I'd rather reload the properties like method 1 instead of doing this.
3. Possibly use some other property loader? But I couldn't find any clear documentation for doing this for my use case.

I feel like there should be a really simple way to just get `Properties`. Is there a straightforward way that I'm missing? Are there better solutions to this problem?

Comment: You have an API that actually literally takes all its options as a `java.util.Properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at @configurationproperties yet

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

http://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Basically, spring will auto inject those properties to the bean it just instantiates.

Note: you need both @Configuration and @configurationproperties to make it work